# PFPurchase restore implementation Parse

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

I am using swift for writing a code and used parse for in app purchases. Apple rejected the app for not having a restore purchase button. I am obviously a beginner.

There is a function in parse's PFPurchase as download asset for transaction.

It is like:

```
PFPurchase.downloadAssetForTransaction(SKPaymentTransaction!, completion: ((String!, NSError!) -> Void)!, progress: PFProgressBlock!)
```

any ideas how to implement this? The action I want this restore to do is the same as purchase button does which is as follows:

```
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "removeAds")
userDefaults.synchronize()
```

anyone have suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found an easier way which is:

```
PFPurchase.restore()
```

As simple as that. If you have added an observer for the product, it automatically invokes any commands implemented in it. This is for non-consumable products I guess. Parse is really much more easier for in-app-purchases implementation then using SKPaymentQueues and switches.

Comment: thanks @sungur for posting. The exact same thing happened to me today. I'm surprised `PFPurchase.restore()` isn't in the Parse docs... or maybe it is and I couldn't find it.